# Trying to reshow hidden elements in a page using jQuery by looping through an array failing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Trying to show and hide sections of a page.
I would like to show only the sections of the page that have matching words from the `conditionsToShow` array.

```
function hideWorkflowConditions() {

    // hide the elements initially
    $('#descriptors_table > tbody').children().css('display', 'none');

}

function showWorkflowConditions() {

    let conditionsToShow = `
    Block transition until approval
    Category is not Empty
    Code Committed
    File Uploader is User
    File Uploader is in Group
    File Uploader is in Project Role
    Has Attachments AM
    Has Links AM
    Hide transition from user
    Limit By Status
    No Open Reviews
    Only Assignee
    Only Reporter
    Permission
    SIL
    Script  [ScriptRunner]
    Sub-Task Blocking
    Unreviewed Code
    User Is In Group
    User Is In Group Custom Field
    User Is In Project Role
    Verify Number of Attachments in Category
    `;

    // create a new array, using the new line break
    let conditionsArray = conditionsToShow.split(/\n/).filter(Boolean);
    // trim the whitespace from the array
    let conditionsArrayTrimmed = conditionsArray.map(Function.prototype.call, String.prototype.trim);

    conditionsArrayTrimmed.forEach(element => {
        // will not work, doesn't give any errors in the console but the entire section stays hidden
        $( "#descriptors_table > tbody > tr (:contains('"+ element +"'))" ).css('display', 'table-row');

    });

}

hideWorkflowConditions();
showWorkflowConditions();

// running this works to show a single, previously hidden element
/*var elx = "Only Reporter";
$( "#descriptors_table > tbody > tr (:contains('"+ elx +"'))" ).css('display', 'table-row');
*/
```

Comment: What specifically is failing? What goes wrong?

Comment: Your selector is invalid because there's a set of parens around `:contains()`

Comment: @showdev trying to hide a table and then show sections of it that matched certain words.  It looks like I had the selector wrong, the selected as answer solves it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selector is invalid with the parens around `:contains()`, and you have a space after the `tr`, which means `:contains()` would be operating on a descendant of the row, instead of the row itself.

```js
function hideWorkflowConditions() {
  $('#descriptors_table > tbody').children().css('display', 'none');
}

function showWorkflowConditions() {
  let conditionsToShow = `
    Block transition until approval
    Category is not Empty
    Code Committed
    File Uploader is User
    File Uploader is in Group
    File Uploader is in Project Role
    Has Attachments AM
    Has Links AM
    Hide transition from user
    Limit By Status
    No Open Reviews
    Only Assignee
    Only Reporter
    Permission
    SIL
    Script  [ScriptRunner]
    Sub-Task Blocking
    Unreviewed Code
    User Is In Group
    User Is In Group Custom Field
    User Is In Project Role
    Verify Number of Attachments in Category
    `;

  // create a new array, using the new line break
  let conditionsArray = conditionsToShow.split(/\n/).filter(Boolean);
  // trim the whitespace from the array
  let conditionsArrayTrimmed = conditionsArray.map(Function.prototype.call, String.prototype.trim)
  .filter(Boolean);

  //console.log(conditionsArrayTrimmed);

  conditionsArrayTrimmed.forEach(element => {
    $("#descriptors_table > tbody > tr:contains('" + element + "')").css('display', 'table-row');

  });

}

hideWorkflowConditions();
showWorkflowConditions();

// running this works to show a single, previously hidden element
/*var elx = "Only Reporter";
$( "#descriptors_table > tbody > tr (:contains('"+ elx +"'))" ).css('display', 'table-row');
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id=descriptors_table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>foo Permission
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>bar
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Also, I added another `.filter(Boolean)` to take care of the whitespace string that resulted from the split.

Comment: Thank you! This works to show and hide the sections of the page.  Thank you for explaining that the space selected the descendant, and the change for the filter.